# About lower semi continuous

Tags: real-analysis

For lower semi continuous
function $f:X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ on compact metric space $(X,
d)$ and sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq X$, we have $
f(x_n)> a$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$.

Question: If $x_n\rightarrow x$. Is it true that $f(x)>a$?

Comment: This is obviously false if you consider continuous functions and $a=f(x)$.

Comment: The following is true: if $f$ is UPPER semicontinuous, and $f(x_n) \ge a$ for all $n$, then $f(x) \ge a$. But using strict inequalities is always a bad idea here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need a proof of it.

Comment: Well, this is actually straighforward by definition. $$f(x) \ge \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \ge a $$ where the first inequality is the definition of upper semicontinuity, while the second inequality follows from the definition of $\limsup$.

Comment: Dear Crostul,   If $f$ is lower semi continuous, $f(x_n)\geq a$ and
$x_n\rightarrow x$, Is it true that $f(x)\geq a$?

Comment: Nope. This is true for upper semicontinuity, but not for lower semicontinuity. As an easy example, take $f(x)= 1$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$, $x_n = 1/n$ and $a=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true consider function $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R},$  $f(t) =t^2$ at point $t=0.$

Comment: But every continuous map preserves convergent sequences.